# Is it bad that I changed the default application of application/x-trash files?

Tags: linux, terminal, mime-types, defaults

I was trying to use the `mimeopen` command to open an image file.  I ended up being asked to pick the default application of application/x-trash.  I was practicing python and thought I should press control c to cancel.  Well now the default application of the application/x-trash files is ^c.  Now I'm wondering if the that's a bad thing and if so how do I change it back to whatever it was.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `mimeopen -d filename` to set a new default program for given mimetype or edit your `mimeapps.list` manually to delete the default program.

On my system, the local configuration file is written to `~/.config/mimeapps.list`.

See the [MIME Applications Associations Spec 1.0.1](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.1.html) for the default
lookup order of the config file and **Default Application** specification.